# How do you trade a career for a life geared toward becoming awakened?

Tags: personal-practice, modern-world

I am a sales person according to my profession. I skip working and wander all over the unknown places, everyday. I just love doing that. But now that I am understanding Buddhist philosophy and am able to relate it to my real world, I am feeling the urge to be awakened. How can I do that with this modern world and its demands upon me?

Comment: Hi jitin. Your question about wanting to stop your worldly routine and focus more on your spiritual needs sounds a bit like this question. There may be something useful to you in this. http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5920/caught-between-two-worlds

Comment: @Robin111, I'm impressed you managed to figure out the meaning enough to provide that link! Would it be worth (you :-) ) editing the question to make that meaning clearer? I was going to try but I just can't get straight precisely what is being asked, especially in the all-important last sentence/question.

Comment: @tkp, I've attempted to clarify what I believe is being asked. Jitin, if I've changed your meaning too much, we can roll it back to the original or you can re-edit if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the book *"Dipa Ma: The Life and Legacy of a Buddhist Master"* by Amy Schmidt. It's a very good illustration of how one can pursue the Buddhist path to a very significant degree, including coming through significant personal tragedy, and still be immersed in the day to day challenges of the world.

Comment: Can I second that recommendation. An inspiring book about practising in daily life

Comment: I completed reading that book, just now. It is helpful @tkp